# What is LLVM Xray Patching?

Tags: clang, llvm, clang++

When we use the functions __xray_patch and __xray_unpatch, what exactly do they do? What does "patching" mean in the context of LLVM Xray?

Comment: Xray adds blocks of [NOPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)) in places where instrumentation code may be wanted. Patching means to overwrite those with instrumentation code; unpatching means to overwrite the instrumentation code with NOPs.

Comment: @arnt, I see that it inserts NOPs while patching, but what can Xray do with the instrumentation points and NOPs?

Comment: The NOP blocks have a certain length. Xray changes those blocks at runtime. If it is to instrument a certain spot, it replaces the NOPs with calls to an instrumentation helper.